# The Space Between Us

Tags: spacetime, atomic-physics, space-expansion, dark-matter, dark-energy

We are told the universe is expanding at anything between 68 and 73km per second, per megaparsec (depending on the places you look) - so by association, the space between us and anything else out there is also expanding, right?

1. Can anyone tell me if there has been any indication that expansion is a potential variable for any orbital change in our solar system?
2. As the universe expands, does, as a result, the space between atoms/molecules/planets then also expanding etc.?
3. I've heard all sorts of stories about the expansion of the universe...

   it is faster than previously thought.

   it is increasing in speed.

   recently, I came across a publication from Oxford University from Oct 2016 that suggests it is staying at a constant speed.

https://www.sciencedaily.com/releases/2016/10/161021123238.htm

I'm now waiting for it to slow down.

has anyone on here worked for or experienced first hand the collecting of that data (or similar), and possibly explain why they think so many different conclusions are being drawn from this subject. as I think I'm right in saying that they analyse the light from collapsing stars and measure their brightness.

4. Could this mean that the universe is expanding at different rates?

Comment: all those have been asked before in another question, have they ?? I don't think so, not all in context, what is the problem dude, why you on my case haha.

Comment: Only 2 is an answerable question, and the answer is  in the duplicate, that the attractive forces making up galaxies and stars and planets systesms and atoms and molecules are very much stronger than the expansion of those distances and remain whole due to the electromagnetic strong and gravitational forces holding them together. 3 is a collection of statements and 4 is about current research  and proposals and cannot be answered except with more research